# Iteration over a multi-index with increasing index-"magnitude"

Tags: matlab, iteration, permutation, multi-index

I have a problem where I need to loop over a multi-index of the type `(a[1],a[2],a[3],...,a[n])`, where `a[i]` ranges between `0` and some integer `m[i]`. In principle, I could of course "simply" use `n` nested for-loops, however, I cannot know `n` ahead of time, so nested loops are out of the question.

**Given inputs:** `n`, `m[1]`,`m[2]`,...,`m[n]`.

**What I already have:** A simple "successor-function" which allows me to step through the index like I would with multiple nested loops; i.e. first `(0,0,0,...)`, `(1,0,0,...)`, ..., `(m[1],0,0,...)`, `(0,1,0,...)`, `(1,1,0,...)`, etc...

MATLAB implementation here:

```matlab
function ii = incr(ii, M)
% multiindex incrementer; ii is a multi-index, M is the upper limits
for i = 1:numel(M)
    ii(i) = ii(i) + 1;
    if i > 1, ii(i-1) = 1; end
    if ii(i) <= M(i), return, end
end
end
```

**What I would like to have:** However, what would be most beneficial would be if I could loop over the indices in order of increasing "magnitude", i.e. `(0,0,0,...)`, `(1,0,0,...)`, `(0,1,0,...)`, ...,`(2,0,0,...)`,`(1,1,0,...)`,...

*The ordering between indices of the same "magnitude" does not particularly matter, it is more important that when ticking up the magnitude it does not decrease again later.*

**Alternative:** An alternative and also acceptable solution would be something which computes a permutation taking the first ordering to any ordering of the second type.

*Edit:* my bad, given that it's MATLAB it of course counts from 1 not 0, so that is what the code-piece does. But the problem remains the same in nature.

**Update (29/05):** So I have worked out a method now, but it is probably not as efficient as it could be (at all). Here it is though. Any improvements and simplifications are appreciated.

```matlab
function a = succ(a,m)
if all(a==m), return; end
n = numel(a);
i = find(a,1);
if i < n
    j = i;
    while a(i+1) +1 > m(i+1)
        i = i+1;
        if i >= n
            i = n;
            break;
        end
    end
    if i == j && a(i) == 1
        a(i) = a(i) -1;
        a(i+1) = a(i+1) +1;
    else
        a(i) = sum(a(j:i));
        a(j:i-1) = 0;
        if i == n
            a = succ_ext(a,m,i,1);
        else
            a = succ_ext(a,m,i,-1);
            a(i+1) = a(i+1) +1;
        end
    end
else
    a = succ_ext(a,m,n,1);
end
end

function a = succ_ext(a,m,i,c)
j = 1;
v = a(i) + c;
a(i) = 0;
while a(j) + v > m(j)
    v = v + a(j)-m(j);
    a(j) = m(j);
    j = j+1;
end
a(j) = a(j) + v;
end
```

**Update (02/06)[A]:** Alternative crude method involves using `incr` as defined above to generate a sequence of "nested loops style". Then summing the components of each computed multi-index to form a sequence of integers. Then sort that list and use the resulting index permutation to permute the original sequence of multi-index.

**Update (02/06)[B]:** I have realized that for computational reasons it was necessary for me too loop in `incr` order during computations, but later representations still benefit from the reordering. Given any desired traversal of the multi-index, say characterized by a successor-style function `succ` taking in an index and producing the next in the traversal sequence, as in my implementations above, we may compute an permutation index map as follows:

The idea is to consider that we are representing integers in a base with different radix for each digit, in particular `m[i]+1` will be the radix for the `i`'th digit.
In this way we may easily compute the corresponding integer representation of each multi-index in a traversal sequence. The integers will be ordered under the nested loop style traversal, so sorting the sequence for the permutation index (let's call it A) gives a map from traversal order to nested loop ordering. If we then sort permutation index A for a new permutation index B, then B will provide the reverse ordering taking us from nested loop order to traversal ordering.